# Как с помощью мыши можно изменить угол поворота

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код. При нажатии на красный шар происходит изменение угла линии с шаром.Каким образом можно с помощью мыши организовать изменение угла(т.е. нажали на правую кнопку мыши, изменили угол на какой нам надо и отпустили кнопку мыши) Может с помощью drag, drop, move? Может есть какие-либо библиотеки, которые могут помощь?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var angle = 0,
    ugol_alpha = 0,
    ugol = 0;
  $("#line").mouseup(function() {
    angle -= 30;
    $(this).css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#fon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 599px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 599px;
  -moz-border-radius: 599px;
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
#ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
  top: 300px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 19px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
  -moz-border-radius: 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="fon">
  <div id="line">
    <div id="ball"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно с событиями `mousedown`, `mousemove` и `mouseup`, и с помощью тригонометрии.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isMoving = false;

  var fon = $("#fon"),
    centerX = fon.offset().left + fon.width() / 2,
    centerY = fon.offset().top + fon.height() / 2;

  $("#line").mousedown(function() {
    isMoving = true;
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (!isMoving) return;
    var x = e.pageX - centerX,
      y = e.pageY - centerY;
    var angle = Math.atan(-x / y);
    if (y < 0) angle += Math.PI;
    $("#line").css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'rad)'
    });
  }).mouseup(function() {
    isMoving = false;
  });
});
```

```css
#fon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 599px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 599px;
  -moz-border-radius: 599px;
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
#ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
  top: 300px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 19px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
  -moz-border-radius: 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="fon">
  <div id="line">
    <div id="ball"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```